# Login logout in smarty

Tags: smarty

I have written the header.tpl and login.php file in smarty.  i want to show the logout text if user  is logged  in. otherwise it should show login if user is not logged in.below is the code of login.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
    $rs=mysql_query("select * from form where name='$name'");
    $fetchdata=mysql_fetch_array($rs);  
        if($rs)
        {
            $name=$fetchdata['name']
            $_SESSION['name']=$name;
            $name1=$_SESSION['name'];
            //$smarty->assign('name',$_SESSION['name']);
            $smarty->assign('name1',$name1);
            $smarty->display("about.tpl");

        }
        else
        {
            $smarty->display("login.tpl");
        }
    }
```

below is the header.tpl code

```
<a href="login.php">{if $name1!= ''}: Logout{else}login{/if}</a>
```

it is showing error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in D:\xampp\htdocs\smarty\login.php on line 29
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bunch of weird things.

1. You should escape the name and pass before inserting into sql query. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for more details.
2. The php documentation recommend that you should use the MySQLi extension
3. I can't see a authentication..I mean you don't use the give password. Is this correct?
4. I think mysql_query isn't falsey even when the result is empty. You can solve this with `if($fetchdata=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){...` instead of `if($rs)`
5. I'm not sure if this would throw an exception but i would write `<a href="login.php">{if {$name1|default:""}!= ''}: Logout{else}login{/if}</a>` instead of `<a href="login.php">{if $name1!= ''}: Logout{else}login{/if}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I ran into a similar issue just a couple minutes ago.

I was getting an parse error for the variable: $_smarty_t

I tried different things to make there error go away, but there was nothing obvious.  I confirmed that caching was turned off, but the issue persisted, even after deleting the individual cached file.

Eventually I deleted the entire contents of that directory and refreshed, and the error finally resolved.

This issue occurred with Smarty v3.1.27, as loaded through Composer, smarty/smarty.